# Why doesn't my :first-child css rule get applied?

Tags: html, css

```
<!-- HTML -->
<section class="row slide">
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>
            <span>Some</span>
            <br />
            <span>Title</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="row slide">
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>
            <em>Some emphasis</em>
            <br />
            <span>Some</span>
            <br />
            <span>Title</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="row slide">
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>
            <em>Some other emphasis</em>
            <br />
            <span>Some</span>
            <br />
            <span>Title</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
</section>


/* CSS */
section h1 span:first-child{
    color:#FF0033;
    }
```

I'm trying to target the first `<span>` in every `<h1>` tag that's in a `<section>` container but as soon as the `<span>` is not the first child element (like the `<em>`) then it's not applying the rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:first-child` selects the first **child**. Use [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-of-type) for your purpose:

```
section h1 span:first-of-type {
    color: #FF0033;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` does not reference the element to be the first child of that type, but generally to be the first child of its parent! [Citing MDN on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-child):

> The `:first-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

What you need is the `:first-of-type` selector ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)) as follows:

```
section h1 span:first-of-type{
  color:#FF0033;
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyLbH/).